# Add different "open" and "if already open" effect to JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, effects

I have found and customized this JQuery script, which displays different content when different links are pressed.

But, when the targetDiv is already visible, i would like the change effect to be fade, so it's only slide effect when you open and close targetDiv.

Also, i can't figure out why the content is visibly in about a half second on page load. Can i avoid that?

Here it is on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/179/

JQuery (newest version):

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();

    jQuery('#close').click(function(){
              jQuery('.targetDiv').slideUp();
    });

        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
              jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
              jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).slideDown();
        });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="buttons">
<a  class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>
<a id="close">Close</a>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>
Lorem Ipsum<br>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/c1_LON8Ib2o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/s4GbpG-PypM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/DHef3iAjxiM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
Lorem Ipsum
```

Comment: For *"when the targetDiv is already visible"* use `:visible` selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/efgFL/2/

Use `is(':visible')` link: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

For the second part the `blah` text is not in any container where the show/hide is happening thats why.

Hope this helps,

**code**

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();

    jQuery('#close').click(function(){
              jQuery('.targetDiv').slideUp();
    });

        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
            if( jQuery('.targetDiv').is(':visible')){
                jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
               jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).fadeIn();
            }else{
              jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
              jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).slideDown();
            }
        });
});​
```

Comment: +1 Exactly that. However, it works awfully with embedded content.

Comment: @VisioN Bruv cheerios! Howz life? < I know & agree about the `Aw` factor `:)` >

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thank you very much! - And btw the embed videos was just som random content to see if the whole thing worked properly.

Comment: @user1410965 Glad it helped `:)` it was a lite talk bruv, have a nice one,